# LWC custom file upload error

Tags: lightning-web-components

I have a custom form built with LWC. In the form it is possible to upload multiple files. Due to styling requirements the standard `lightning-file-upload` cant be used and I am therefore using the html `<input type="file" />`

I am getting the following error when file sizes become to large.

> Communication error, please retry or reload the page

Is there a file size limit when creating files with LWC and AuraEnabled methods?

JS Method processing file upload.

```
  onFileUpload(event) {
    const file = event.target.files[0];
    let reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = () => {
      let base64 = reader.result.split(',')[1];
      let fileData = {
        label: file.name,
        base64: base64
      };
      this.files.push(fileData);
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  }
```

Apex method that is called on form submission

```
  @AuraEnabled
  public static void createFiles(MyObject__c record, String files) {
    
    
      List<File> deserializeFiles = (List<File>) JSON.deserialize(files, List<File>.class);

      
      generateContentDocumentLinks(record.Id, generateContentVersions(deserializeFiles, applicationNumber));
    
  }
```

Comment: How big are the file sizes that are throwing the error? I presume [file size limits](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.collab_files_size_limits.htm&type=5) could be the culprit.

Comment: I tested with one file 2.6MB which was fine and another 28MB which triggered the error.

Comment: Around 3MB is when the error starts to show up.

Comment: What do debug logs show for limits - in particular, [heap size](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000321537&type=1)?

Comment: Debug logs are not being generated. Apex never even runs. I am thinking that the error occurs when calling and passing the parameters to the AuraEnabled method. Do you know of any limits here? Now I am getting new error when submitting "Received exception event aura:systemError from server".

Comment: Looks like it is probably hitting this limit https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_lc_client_data_limit.htm&type=5&release=210

Comment: try splitting the file in chunks to 2 MB and append version data in chunks. https://www.sfdcpanther.com/custom-file-uploader-using-lightning-web-component/